# How to add mousDown event in chromium browser c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I use in chromium webBrowser WPF in my program c# and when I tried to add a mouseDown event it doesn't work.
my chromium control in a userControl.
any idea?

XAML:

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser  
        Address="H:\jsWpfNativApp\jsWpfNativApp\html-resources\examples\index3.html"   
        Name="browser" 
        Margin="0,1,0,0" 
        Grid.Row="1"  
        MouseDown="browser_MouseDown"  >
 </cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

c#:

```
private void browser_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ddd");           
}
```

noting is not working even this simple line

Comment: Please show us some of Your work.

Comment: My car broke, and it doesn't work - do you see the analogy? We need you to provide examples / code to be able to try solve your problem - otherwise its a guessing game. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Even if English isn't your first language, try to proof read, and provide your non working code, or even better a minimal example that doesn't work. because the question : "it doesn't work, any idea?" gets the answer: "yes, make it work".

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain.

Comment: How do you bind / call that method ? Can you add the caller's code ?

Comment: what is caller's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PreviewMouseDown` event instead of `MouseDown`, I guess it would make it work.